# Make Simultaneous Rest API calls using FeignClient in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

Let's say I have 2 microservices A and B. Now for a particular request on service A, A needs to make multiple API calls of the same API to B(with different parameters). Initially, I had used feign client for making rest calls between microservices[with implicit support for load balancing, service discovery and adding port metadata etc. from Feign client].

The problem with this approach, the calls are synchronous and are taking a lot of time. How/ What to use to fire off multiple requests and wait for the response in a non-blocking and asynchronous way?

TIA!

Comment: Feign is blocking by design. See https://github.com/Playtika/feign-reactive

Comment: If you are looking for a declarative REST client that supports WebClient under the hood, you can also take a look at Spring Cloud Square: https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-cloud-square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can consider **Spring WebClient which is an asynchronous, non-blocking solution provided by the Spring Reactive framework.**

And of course, you can make simultaneous calls too. Example,

```
Mono<String> response1 = request1();
Mono<String> response2 = request2();

Mono.zip(response1, response2)
        .flatMap(result -> transformer(result));
```

Comment: Hi @Sam , I have seen webclients using explicit URL for any requests. However, with feign its auto resolved in a multi-pod environment. How can this be achieved using webclient? Sorry, I am asking very low-level details as am very new to this reactive paradigm!

Comment: @DeekshithAnand Hi, you can achieve that Please refer this example : https://developpaper.com/how-to-use-openfeignwebclient-to-realize-non-blocking-interface-aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExecutorServices to create two tasks and use CompletableFutures to capture the two responses from the two microservices

Comment: Hi @jayaneetha, I used this approach earlier, and the requests are fired off from those executor threads. But they are still blocking in those executor threads. Moreover, if hystrix is enabled, I had seen feign logs on those hystrix threads, from which I had inferred that the requests are furthermore delegated to hystrix threads from the dedicated executor threads.